# Creating a puzzle

Tags: python, binary, puzzle

For my study I need to create a binary puzzle in Python like this:

[image: Puzzle layout]

First I need to make a game board for it, as in the image. I'm trying to create a 6 by 6 board. The player must be able to enter a `1` or `0`.

How do I create the board so that the player will be able to enter the coordinate as in the picture?

After some research I found this way to create a board:

```
col = 6
row = 6
board = []
for i in range(6):
   board.append(["0"]*col)

 print(board)
```

The problem here is that the list is coming up like:

```
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ...]
```

How can I change the code so that it will come under each other?

And how can I add those `A`, `B`, `C` / `1`, `2`, `3` on the `x`/`y` axes?

Comment: *"Is this the right way to do it"* - does it work? If yes, then what exactly are your concerns?

Comment: it doesn't work, im creating a list and getting a grid. but its without any x-y axis information.  2nd issue is the filling of the coordinates

Comment: What *"x-y axis information"* were you expecting?!

Comment: well i want to create a field of 6 by 6. on the Y- i want numbers and on the X- i want letters. but when i make a field with list i don't know how to get the information next to it. hope its more clear now

Comment: Your `puzzle` doesn't include any of that - it won't magically appear, you have to include it yourself. I don't know what you mean by either of *"a field with list"* or *"the information next to it"*. Perhaps you could provide an example of what you want, compared to what you have?

Comment: im tring to create a board that can have 3 sizes, 6by6,8by8,10by10. that wil depend on user input.

Comment: That didn't clarify anything. Focus on getting one size right, then try different sizes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i edited my question and added a other image, perhaps it is understandable for you

Comment: That's two questions. The answer to the first is: print each `row` on a separate line. The answer to the second is: add them in when you create the `board`, or when you `print` it. However, **this is not a code-writing service**; do your own homework.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i didn't asked for code-writing-service :) just some help for the problems i couldn't find a solution for. thnx for the answer on q1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple to give you some idea:

```
y_map = {'A':0, 'B':1, 'C':2, 'D':3, 'E':4, 'F':5}

def get_coords(coord_str):
    x,y = coord_str.split()
    x -= 1
    y = y_map[y]
    return (x,y)

user_coords = "A 4"
user_input = 1
user_coords = get_coords(user_coords)
grid[user_coords[1]][user_coords[0]] = user_input
```

Needs a bit of work, but I'm sure it's enough to get started.

Comment: thanks il get a look at that, first getting my game board fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Before printing the board print the letters one after the next. You also will not want to say `print(board)` but instead create your own function to print the board or do it inside a a nested `for` loop. Print the row label after printing all elements in that row.

```
def printBoard():
    col_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    row_labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    for i in col_labels:
        print(i)
        print(" ")

    for r in range(row):
        for c in range(col):
            print(board[r][c]
            print(" ")
        print(row_labels[r])
```

NOTE: untested code